# Absolute import doesn't work in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a directory set up like this

```
Project
   |
   |folder1
   |  |folder2
   |  |  |Script_A.py
   |
   |folder3
   |  |Script_B.py
```

I am trying to access a class named **ClassB** residing in **Script_B.py** from **Script_A.py** in Python 3.7. I am trying to achieve this using absolute imports. Here is the content of Script_A.py:

```
from folder3.Script_B import ClassB
```

There seems to be something I am missing. I don't understand how **Script_A** is supposed to be aware of the existence of **Script_B** or even of the folder **folder3** or even of **Project**. What tells python to look for these folders?

I have read [PEP328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) and this doesn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: you need an `__init__.py` file in the Script_B folder

Comment: Exactly how are you invoking Script_A? Which directory are you in when you do so?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm invoking it from folder2.

Comment: @Axois simply adding this results in the same `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder3'`

Comment: I think the issue is that you are importing Script_B.py in Script_A.py, however Script_A.py has to be in the `main` folder, which in your case should be the Project folder. This is because python is unable to locate the root folder of your directory

Comment: (**edit**)One other solution is to put the directory containing Package into your `PYTHONPATH` to use absolute imports, or you can use Prayson's sys method, without requiring to manually set it.

Comment: while you're invoking it (folder3) from 'folder2' , where the 'folder2' cannot reach folder3. 
It isn't absolute. you didn't take it to the main-package level, you are still talking at 'subpackage' level.  (ie. you are still at RELATIVE import, NOT at the ABSOLUTE import level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use  `__init__.py`, just an empty file,  that transform folders to modules:

```sh
package/
    __init__.py
    subpackage1/
        __init__.py
        moduleX.py
        moduleY.py
    subpackage2/
        __init__.py
        moduleZ.py
        subpackage2_1/
              __init___.py
              deep_module.py
module_test.py
```

This will allow(in `module_test.py`)

```py
from package.subpackage2.subpackage2_1 import deep_module
```

If deep_module has a class Foo

```py
# deep_module.py
class Foo: pass
```

We can import Foo as

```py
from package.subpackage2.subpackage2_1.deep_module import Foo
```

I would not recommend this kind of imports as they are hard to debug.

You could do:

```py
from package.subpackage2.subpackage2_1 import deep_module

# it helps to know where class is coming from
foo = deep_module.Foo()
```

Which is better than importing Foo directly but yet still I will always try to avoid it for readability sake  ;)

If the call is made in package directory, then

```py
from subpackage2.subpackage2_1 import deep_module
```

#### Terrible Idea

Or  this, that will work everywhere

```py
# terrible hack is to add your package to your sys path
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'path_to_package')

from package.subpackage2.subpackage2_1 import deep_module
```

#### Better Idea

Run your script with PYTHONPATH

```sh
PYTHONPATH="$PWD/path_to_package"  python code.py
```

Comment: I just tried this and I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Project'`

Comment: This is because you are calling a package in Project :). I will edit my answer to explain this